# How do I use the color palette (FBIOPUTCMAP)?

Tags: linux, debian, dd, framebuffer, powerpc

I am trying to track down the following [issue](https://bugs.debian.org/825840) in Debian Jessie on PowerPC. Per `bogl-bterm` package maintainer the issue is simply that `bterm` makes uses of FBIOPUTCMAP, see ref [here](https://bugs.debian.org/825840#196).

So before even trying to patch the linux kernel, I would like to prepare a simple way to reproduce the issue as the original report is done within a minimal setup during Debian installation process. It would be a lot of pain to install `localechooser` on a regular Debian system since this is a `udeb` package.

So I would like to know if a Linux framebuffer expert could point me in the right direction to reproduce this palette inversion ?

I had naively assumed that I would be able to reproduce the bug using something as simple as:

Print in blue:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1K count=600 | tr '\000' '\001' > /dev/fb0
```

Print in red:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1K count=600 | tr '\000' '\004' > /dev/fb0
```

But since it does not work, this means I am playing directly with the color buffer of the framebuffer instead of using the palette one.

What tools can I install on a regular Debian system (PowerPC) to play with the palette (FBIOPUTCMAP) ?

---

Update: the description of the above symptoms may be relatively confusing, but really what I am looking is minimal code that exercise `ioctl/FBIOGETCMAP/FBIOPUTCMAP` so as to see the red / blue inversion in minimal code.

Comment: `FBIOPUTCMAP` refers to an `ioctl` call.  Writing to the raw device probably is the wrong approach.

Comment: No one's written a tutorial for this; you can easily find it used in source-code, e.g., [this](https://svn.enlightenment.org/svn/e/tags/evas-1.7.0/src/modules/engines/fb/evas_fb_main.c).